# file_get_contents() seems to cut off boundary

Tags: php, wordpress, post, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to make a `POST` request to a remote server with the goal of uploading an image file to it. I'm trying to utilize PHP's [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) method to output the file in a string format, however it seems to cut off the last boundary in the `POST` body.

PHP code where I'm setting up my `POST` body and headers:

```
$boundary = '------------' . uniqid();

$curl->setHTTPHeader( array(
    'Accept' => 'application/xml',
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' . $boundary
) );

$img_data = getimagesize( $img_file );

$file_contents = file_get_contents( $img_file );

$xml_body = "\r\n";
$xml_body .= $boundary . "\r\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\n" .
              "<Image><filename>" . basename( $img_file ) . "</filename>" .
                "<description>test</description>" .
            "</Image>" .
            "\r\n\r\n" .
            $boundary . "\r\n";

$xml_body .= "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"" . basename( $img_file ) . "\"\r\n" .
             "Content-Type: " . $img_data['mime'] . "\r\n" .
             "\r\n" . $file_contents . "\r\n" .
             $boundary . "--"; // <-- this part doesn't seem to show up in the body

$body = $xml_body;
```

When I try to print out (using `error_log()`) the body before the request is made, it seems like the lower boundary is cut off:

```
[16-Mar-2016 06:15:45 UTC] Array
(
    [method] => POST
    [timeout] => 60
    [redirection] => 5
    [httpversion] => 1.1
    [user-agent] => [redacted]
    [reject_unsafe_urls] => 
    [blocking] => 1
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [Accept] => application/xml
            [Content-Type] => multipart/form-data;boundary=------------56e8fa112c4b0
            [connection] => close
            [Accept-Encoding] => deflate;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=0.5
            [Content-Length] => 152510
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [body] => 
------------56e8fa112c4b0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

<Image><filename>my-pic.jpg</filename><description></description></Image>

------------56e8fa112c4b0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="my-pic.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿà
```

I'm curious about 2 things:

1) Am I setting up the request correctly? Right now when I test it, the remote server is responding with a `401` http status code, which means it's not working.

2) Why is the lower boundary not showing up in my error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good based on the code.  A `401` response means you are not authorized.  Are you missing any authorization headers, login cookies, or some other kind of authentication parameters?

The fact that you aren't getting a `400 Bad Request` response indicates it is at least well formed per the HTTP and MIME spec.

The lower boundary (and most of the image data from the looks of it) are cut off because, according to the PHP manual, the [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function is not binary safe:

> **Warning** - `error_log()` is not binary safe. **`message`** will be truncated by
>   null character.

Since the image contains null characters, everything after the first one is cut off by the function.  You can debug your request by writing it to a file with `file_put_contents`, or you can try using a packet sniffer like Wireshark if the site you're posting to doesn't use HTTPS (or you can opt not to use it).

Comment: I was missing the `Authorization` header. Now I'm getting a `405` so at least I'm making it through. The remote server is suggesting I'm not sending an "input body" with my POST request, but after doing a bit of debugging AFAIK the body is being sent through - any recommendations on next steps to figure out why I'm getting a `405` response? I also tested via postman and was able to make the same request with no problems.

Comment: 405 means method not allowed as you know.  In that case the first thing I'd check is if you should be doing PUT instead of POST, and make sure the exact URL is correct.  Maybe you also need to have a `Content-type: application/xml` header in the XML part.